# Element type is invalid: expected a string or a class/function but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

Please help me find the issue I'm learning react-native.

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

```
import { View, Text } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs'
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'

import HomeScreen from './Screens/HomeScreen'
import DetailsScreen from './Screens/DetailsScreen'
import SettingsScreen from './Screens/Settings'


const homeName = 'Home';
const settingsName = 'Settings';
const detailName = 'Details';


const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator()

export default function MainContainer() {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Tab.Navigator
                initialRouteName={homeName}
                screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
                    tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {
                        let iconName;
                        let routeName = route.name
                        if (routeName == homeName) {
                            iconName = focused ? 'home' : 'home-outline'
                        } else if (routeName == settingsName) {
                            iconName = focused ? 'list' : 'list-outline'
                        } else if (routeName == detailName) {
                            iconName = focused ? 'settings' : 'settings-outline'
                        }


                        return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />
                    },
                })}>

                <Tab.Screen name='Home' component={HomeScreen} />


            </Tab.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    )
}
```

App.js

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { MainContainer } from './Navigation/MainContainer';

function App() {
  return (
    <MainContainer />
  );
}
```

Error:

Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the defined file, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `ExpoRoot`.

This error is located at:
in ExpoRoot
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in DevAppContainer (created by AppContainer)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in AppContainer
in main(RootComponent)
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:95:4 in reportException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:141:19 in handleException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/setUpErrorHandling.js:24:6 in handleError
at node_modules/expo-error-recovery/build/ErrorRecovery.fx.js:12:21 in ErrorUtils.setGlobalHandler$argument_0

Comment: Does every imported component have an "export default ..." clause? (StatusBar, HomeScreen, DetailsScreen, SettingsScreen?

Comment: @ChrisNeve Yes Chris

Comment: What does the error say exactly? This kind of error usually gives a hint about the problematic component.

Comment: @ChrisNeve i have edited the post please see the exact error i'm having.

Comment: It clearly says the problem is with "ExpoRoot". Please have a look at that.

Comment: Most likely you have forgotten to export one of your components or screen,

check your AppContainer, DevAppContainer, MainContainer, HomeScreen, DetailsScreen, SettingsScreen.

Secondly, You might have exported it but in an incorrect way. Try to mostly use default exports.